# Normalizing query result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a setup in which many 1 nodes are connected to multiple nodes.

[image]

SO when I fetch some paths, those 1 nodes connected to multiples nodes gets repeated in query result

```
MATCH (r:Red)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r:Red)-[rel]-(g:Grey)
RETURN ID(r), g.prop, rel.prop
```

returns

```
ID(r)   g.prop  rel.prop
1131    null    null
>1132   b       value1
>1132   b2      value2
>1132   b3      value3
1134    c       value4
```

And then I convert this into usable javascript array/object

```
results.forEach(function(result){
    Red.push({
        red: result['ID(r)'],
        Grey: {
            greyProp: result['g.prop'],
            greyRelation: result['r.prop']
        }
    });
});
```

which generates

```
Red:
[
{"red":1131,"Grey":{"greyProp":null,"greyRelation":null}}
,
{"red":1132,"Grey":{"greyProp":"b","greyRelation":"value1"}}
,
{"red":1132,"Grey":{"greyProp":"b2","greyRelation":"value2"}}
,
{"red":1132,"Grey":{"greyProp":"b3","greyRelation":"value3"}}
,
{"red":1134,"Grey":{"greyProp":"c","greyRelation":"value4"}}
]
```

But I would rather have it as

```
Red:
[
{"red":1131,"Grey":{"greyProp":null,"greyRelation":null}}
,
{"red":1132,"Grey":
    [
        {"greyProp":"b","greyRelation":"value1"},
        {"greyProp":"b2","greyRelation":"value2"},
        {"greyProp":"b3","greyRelation":"value3"}
    ]
,
{"red":1134,"Grey":{"greyProp":"c","greyRelation":"value4"}}
]
```

I can't think of a way to do this. Would I need to run the query again when I'm making the object from the result from the first query? Or is there a simpler less complex way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do this

```
MATCH (r:Red)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r:Red)-[rel]-(g:Grey)
RETURN ID(r), collect(g.prop) as g_prop, collect(rel.prop) as rel_prop
```

This will give you result like

```
ID(r)   g_prop        rel_prop
1131    null          null
1132    [b,b2,b3]     [value1,value2,value3]
1134    c             value4
```

**As per the drawback pointed out by laggingreflex. The modified query that will place a 'NULL' String in the collection in places where there are no rel props found.(Assuming all the `g.prop` is `never null` in case it is then similarly use `case .. when` inside `collect(g.prop)`)

```
MATCH (r:Red)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r:Red)-[rel]-(g:Grey)
RETURN ID(r), collect(g.prop) as g_prop, collect(case when rel.prop is null then 'null' 
else rel.prop end) as rel_prop
```

This will give you result like

```
ID(r)   g_prop        rel_prop
1131    null          null
1132    [b,b2,b3]     [value1,'null',value3]
1134    c             value4
```

Comment: One (major) drawback is that `rel_prop` is completely independent of `g_prop`. i.e. I was able to reproduce `1132    [b,b2,b3]     [value1,value3]` (by deleting `value2`, which is internally a dependent relationship of b2)